# Use Javascript function inside PHP site

Tags: javascript

Is there a possibility to integrate a Javascript code inside a PHP page? If I try it it simply ignores the code and nothing happens.

I already added a Javascript code inside the PHP site and that also works like a charm. That is another content locker that appears directly after the site has loaded and forces the user to like the site.

However, if I try to add the other Javascript code it doesn't work as I already mentioned.

It's that plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/share-photo-tag-friends-to-unlock-for-jquery-/3846565

The problem is that the hidden content is visible and not hidden. It simply ignores the code!

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#locked-content").postAndTagToUnlock({
        uniqid: '1234567',
        header_text: 'This Content is Locked !!',
        button_text: 'Post Photo & Tag Friends to Unlock',
        facebook_app_id: 4557660908660,
        num_friends: 4,
        image_url: 'wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/3b/Dark_Side_of_the_Moon.png/220px-Dark_Side_of_the_Moon.png',
        image_text: 'You can even add a link here in addition to a description \n\n http://google.com'
    });
});
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server side, JavaScript on the client. PHP often generates HTML which is then interpreted by the browser and HTML can contain JavaScript. So if that's what you mean, then yes, it is possible. If you have a specific question regarding *your* code, then you should post the code and explain the problem.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: How are you integrating the Javascript in php? Are you using proper tags which are needed for php as well as js?

Comment: Erm... why would you want to do this? Why switch back and forth between languages? Your just going to end up looking a right mess, and you'll make a lot more mistakes, because of having to switch languages all the time, and what if you actually have to _include client-side JS in the output?_

Comment: erm, your ignorance may be too evident. The first thing I'll recommend as remedy is to 1) understand what PHP is, what it does, where it does it; 2) understand what the client is, how it works with the server; 3) understand what javascript is, what it does, where it does it; 4) integrate the concepts to have an overview of the process behind the client-request <-> server-response from start to finish

Comment: I want to add a "share locker" inside a PHP site so that the user has to share an image in order to unlock the desired content. The whole page is PHP but if I try to add the Javascript it doesn't work and it simply ignores the code.

Answer (score 0):

no it is not since js normally runs on the clients computer and php on the server.
There is a way of server side javascript, but then without php, read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Server-Side_JavaScript